# How to download servlet 3 dependency that works with tomcat 7

Tags: jakarta-ee, maven-2, maven, tomcat7, servlet-3.0

i was using servlet 2.5 as follows:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

and i want to use servlet 3 since i am migrating to **tomcat 7** so i can use **EL 2.2**, when i added the following dependency, it couldn't be found:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

**UPDATE:**

I am using **Spring 3**, **JSF 2**, **Tomcat 7**

so what do you guys suggest ?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Looks like artifact ID has been renamed to `javax.servlet-api`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Here is the search URL on maven central: http://search.maven.org/#search|gav|1|g%3A%22javax.servlet%22

To preempt your question about JSP and EL, here are the dependencies for jsp-api and el-api:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I have really no idea if it works (Maven is beyond me), but this is at least more suitable for Tomcat as it's not a Java EE Web Profile compliant container at all (which would only result in future classpath troubles). So, here's a +1 to put it above the other answer suggesting that.

Comment: i thought about that too, that's why i compared between this jar and the servlet-api in tomcat 7 lib but i found that the one from tomcat contains two additional packages jsp,resources, are you pretty sure that this is the correct one ?

Comment: What happens then if you try that?

Comment: @BalusC and @Alexander Pogrebnyak  it couldn't parse the following: `<h:dataTable value="#{user.getUsers()}"` any ideas ?

Comment: So, no compilation errors or abstract runtime errors due to classpath collisions anymore? Then your initial question is answered and your problem is solved! Your new problem is caused by something else (hint: `web.xml` version).

Comment: @BalusC my web.xml is version 3, and i don't have any EL 2.1 version on my pom file, any other ideas ?

Comment: @Mika. `<h:dataTable>` looks like a JSF tag.  Do you have JSF in your web-app pom's dependency list?

Comment: yes i do, `<dependency>
     <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
     <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
     <version>2.1.0-b11</version>
     <scope>compile</scope>
     </dependency>

     <dependency>
     <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
     <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
     <version>2.1.0-b11</version>
     <scope>compile</scope>
     </dependency> `

Comment: @Alexander Pogrebnyak but i guess i knew the problem, that maven tomcat plugin for maven 2 only runs the tomcat 6 instance, so i need to configure it to run the tomcat 7 instance, any useful links or ideas for this issue ?

Comment: So, it doesn't look like these match exactly; I'm not seeing any runtime problems, the only thing is that the sources for that servlet library and the debug information is not really in sync.

Answer (score 10):

The library org.apache.tomcat contains Servlet 3.0

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.30</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

For further reference see:

1. https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-mvc-showcase/blob/master/pom.xml
2. https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-mvc-showcase/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml